# Don't understand memory analysis

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-management, clang-static-analyzer

I have upgraded my XCode to versio 3.2.3 to support iOS4 on my iphone project. using the static analyser I checked for memory management problems.

In one of my routines I get the following problem: 
I generate a user alert after adding an event to the calendar to give him a status.

This runs fine, but the memory analyser doesn't like how I defined the alert.
I can't see the coding problem, do you? (I indicated the memory analyser hints with "<<<<")

```
- (IBAction) addToCalendar {
        ...
    UIAlertView  *tmpAlert  = [UIAlertView alloc];        <<<<Method returns an Objective-C object with a+1 retain count (owning reference)

    calData.startDate   = iVar.zeitVon;
    calData.endDate     = iEvent.zeitBis;
    calData.title       = iVar.title;
    calData.calendar    = myEventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents;

    if ([tmpEventStore saveEvent:tmpEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&tmpSaveError]) {
        // Show a save success dialog
        [tmpAlert initWithTitle:@"Success"        <<<<Object released
                        message:@"entry saved" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    } else {
        // Show a save error dialog
        [tmpAlert initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                        message:@"entry not saved" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] ;
    }
    [tmpAlert show];                               <<<<Reference counted object is used after its released
    [tmpAlert release];
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never decouple `alloc` and `init`. `init` often changes the object behind the scenes! Try

```
NSString* foo=[NSString alloc]; 
NSLog(@"%p %@", foo, [foo class]);
foo=[foo initWithString:@"bar"]; 
NSLog(@"%p %@", foo, [foo class]);
```

You'll see something like

```
2010-07-14 01:00:55.359 a.out[17862:903] 0x10010d080 NSPlaceholderString
2010-07-14 01:00:55.363 a.out[17862:903] 0x100001070 NSCFString
```

This shows that `+[NSString alloc]` doesn't really allocate anything; rather, what does the job is `initWithString` itself. I don't think `UIAlertView` does this, but you never know.

To recap: never decouple `alloc` and `init`. I think the static analyzer just assumes that everyone use `[[... alloc] init]`, so that it got confused by your code. The analyzer should have warned you not to decouple `alloc` and `init`.

Comment: yeah, I now changed the routine to have the 2 2gether (alloc & init) and the warning disappeared, thanks you :)

Comment: Please file a bug report (about not warning decoupled alloc init) to the LLVM static analyzer team here: http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/filing_bugs.html  and do the community a favor!